# Clear cache stored only for a certain website

Tags: javascript, html, websphere

I hava a `file.js` which has to erase the cache and redirect to a different page in order to log out of a WebSphere (.war) application. I tried to somehow delete the cookies that are being created during the log in and didn't work.

Is there a way to delete the cache only of a certain page? or any other solutions you can think of.

here is the code I have that deletes the cache:

```
function clearBrowserAuthenticationCache() {

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');
    }
    else {
        // https://website.com/index.html
         var pathArray = "https://" + window.location.host +"/index.html" ; 
        // window.location.replace("https://website.com/index.html/jsp/http401.jsp");
        // Let's create a dummy xmlhttp object
        var dummyXmlhttp = createXMLObject();
        // Let's prepare invalid credentials
        dummyXmlhttp.open('GET',pathArray, true, 'logout', 'logout');
        // Let send the request to the server
        dummyXmlhttp.send(null);
        // Let's abort the request
        dummyXmlhttp.abort();
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it "deletes" all my sesions in the browser that I have. 
Also the delete cache only works on IE but not on Chrome or Firefox.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: what kind of cache you want to clear? Do you want to remove session cookie and ltpa cookie?

Comment: Yes I have 2 cookies that are being build on log-in but I am not sure if deleting them would work. The credentials are being passed through the URL from an AD log-in to the application

Comment: @fnt Please stop removing WebSphere tag, you are doing it much too often. In this question it actually might be related, since each server provides its own logout method and it is important as the answer might be different.

Comment: Do you have application security enabled and are you using container authentication? If yes, it is much better to use server provided logout methods or Servlet API rather than manually remove cookies via javascript. So in case of WebSphere you may post request to [/ibm_security_logout](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_pofolo.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-12-2-7-3&lang=en) to clear session and authentication data for the given user.

Comment: @Gas I don't think you have the function here to decide it is too often or not. This is community-edited site, you are free to add 'websphere' tag if you find the question on-topic.

Comment: @fnt I'm just asking you to consider a little bit more, before you remove certain tags, as it might be useful and on topic for others even, if it looks at the beginning for you as not relevant.

Comment: @Gas yes I tried the Ibm_security_logout but since there are a lot of JVMs on the WebSphere I am not able to change the security. Also I think that the application is being disconnected but since there is an AD that keeps the username in url it relogs me. Thank you for your help Gas !

Comment: I was looking for a code like this :                                       function delete_cookie( name, path, domain ) {
  if( get_cookie( name ) ) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+
      ((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}  what would be path when i call the function.

Comment: You can check the cookie path in the browser, for example in FireFox.